# Is there any way to fix error while running below code, which will generate excel file from datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am generating excel file report from datagridview with data (400000 rows)in vb in visual studio.

I have tried this code,which works fine when I use '0' in place of 'counterx'.
but i have to increase the counterx on every loop so it will take every row one by one..and later i can simply use other loop to make things faster.

```
        counterx = 0
        Do While (remains > 0)
        Dim rawData3(0, DataGridView4.Columns.Count - 1) As Object

        For col = 0 To DataGridView4.Columns.Count - 1

        rawData3(0, col) = DataGridView4.Rows(counterx).Cells(col).Value

        Next
        counterx += 1
        Dim excelstart3 As String = String.Empty
        TextBox4.Text = counterx

        excelstart3 = ((counterx) + 1).ToString()
        TextBox8.Text = "A" & excelstart3 & ":{0}{1}"
        Dim finalColLetter1 As String = String.Empty
        finalColLetter1 = ExcelColName(DataGridView4.Columns.Count)
        Dim excelRange3 As String = String.Format("A" & excelstart3 & ":{0}{1}", finalColLetter1, counterx + 1) 'firstphase + 1 )

        Ws.Range(excelRange3, Type.Missing).Value2 = rawData3


        ' secondphase = secondphase - 1
        remains = remains - 1
    Loop
```

Comment: it works fine if i use '0' in place of 'counterx' but when i use counterx it will run for a while and gives error at 137418' row.

Comment: counterx is integer

Comment: Would you  mind sharing what that error is? Usually they are important as to why your program stopped working.

Comment: 'An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll ' this error displays on 'counterx'